# How to use Text Watcher for multiple edit text in android?

Tags: android, android-textwatcher

I have a situation where there will be two EditText controls, one for entering Rate Before Tax value and another one for entering Rate After Tax. I will be changing both Rate BT and Rate AT values. When I change Rate BT, then Rate AT text should change depending on Rate BT and vice versa.

Please help

Comment: Can you post some code to help us to help you

Comment: It is possible to do it by setting two textwatchers for each edittexts; like...

for Text2 : 
onTextChanged() {
//change text 1
}

For text1:
onTextChanged() {
//change text2
}

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it as by adding `TextWatcher` to your edittext as,

```
rateAtEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             // you can do it here, what you want to do when RateAt text change
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

rateBtEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // you can do it here, what you want to do when RateBt text change
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```